# Can spinors be written this way?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spinors, clifford-algebra

I've used Geometric Algebra to rewrite Quantum Mechanics in a slightly different way than what I've seen in text books so far. Some equations seem to become [neater](https://github.com/Gerenuk/Quantum-Mechanics-Geometric-Algebra/blob/main/qm-ga-gerenuk.pdf). I wonder if a particular expression I get can be related to spinors (see section "Other ideas" in the document). The question is:

Is it possible to identify
$$
\Psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(e_1f_0\,\alpha_1+f_1e_0\,\alpha_2+e_1e_0\,\alpha_3-f_1f_0\,\alpha_4+e_2f_0\,\alpha_5+f_2e_0\,\alpha_6+e_2e_0\,\alpha_7-f_2f_0\,\alpha_8\right)
$$
for real $\alpha_i$ as a spinor somehow? By means of commutator relations maybe? $e_0,e_1,e_2,f_0,f_1,f_2$ are orthonormal vectors. The operation that will be performed as the next step is $\Psi\Psi^\dagger$, so this the the type of multiplication that matters.

Equivalently, you could write
$$
\Psi f_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(e_1(\alpha_1+J\,\alpha_3)+f_1(\alpha_4+J\,\alpha_2)+e_2(\alpha_5+J\,\alpha_7)+f_2(-\alpha_8+J\,\alpha_6)\right)
$$
with $J=e_0f_0$ if that helps.

Comment: The link you posted seems broken? As far as I understand GA, Spinors are linear combinations of vectors, not bi-vectors.

Comment: @KurtG. Oh, weird. The link works for me and points to a public Github repo. Maybe try again? I had the impression that textbooks do it differently. But I can at least say that the above form reproduces classical QM. Not sure about spinors, because I don't know them. How else can I send the PDF to you? Btw, the second equation is also 4 vectors with complex numbers.

Comment: don't worry. It will work when I go to another computer later today. It might also be that my remark about GA Spinors was an over simplification to say the least. It is an interesting subject by all means.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hope you can see the PDF. The first two pages should already give you an idea.

Comment: Maybe this link has something to do with your research 
 http://ipmras.ru/UserFiles/publications/mironov/JMP_Electrodinamics.pdf

Comment: and https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234361049_Octonic_First-Order_Equations_of_Relativistic_Quantum_Mechanics

Comment: @Gerenuk : the majority of physicists is probably a lot more familiar with Spinors formulated in terms of Pauli matrices (for non relativistic QM) resp. Dirac matrices for relativistic spin 1/2 particles. Your notes will interest more people when you compare new things to old things. A short introduction to GA or some reference to pedagogical papers would be of great help. At the moment I only see terse notes from someone who seems very familiar with GA in $n$ (yes!) dimensions. GA in 3 dimensions is easy, and in 3+1 it is still worth to explain it to those familiar with Dirac Spinors.